# Данные не отправляются постом

Tags: php, html

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

```
    $width = trim($_POST['fbrush-width']);
  $height = trim($_POST['fbrush-height']);
$areaM = trim($_POST['areaM']);
$color = trim($_POST['fbrush-color']);
$glue = trim($_POST['fbrush-glue']);
$cost = trim($_POST['cost']);
$orient = trim($_POST['orient']);
$sizeWidthSm= trim($_POST['sizeWidthSm']);
$sizeHeightSm = trim($_POST['sizeHeightSm']);
$offset = trim($_POST['offset']);
$textureId = trim($_POST['textureId']);
$filtersMask = trim($_POST['filtersMask']);
$costView= trim($_POST['costView']);
$textureView = trim($_POST['textureView']);
$stripsCountView = trim($_POST['stripsCountView']);
$sname= trim($_POST['sname']);
$fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
$city = trim($_POST['city']);
$email= trim($_POST['email']);
$phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
$comment = trim($_POST['comment']);
 $paytype = trim($_POST['paytype']);
 $gogo = trim($_POST['gogo']);

//Если ошибок нет, отправить email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'tarasowgeorgij@yandex.ru'; //Сюда введите Ваш email
    $body = "Ширина: $width \n\Высота: $height \n\Не знаю: $areaM \n\Цвет:\n $color \n\НЕ знаю:$glue \n\Цена $cost \n\не знаю $orient 
\n\см $sizeWidthSm \n\ширина $sizeHeightSm \n\что то $offset \n\текстуры $textureId \n\Маска $filtersMask
 \n\Цена $costView \n\Текстура $textureView \n\Что то $stripsCountView \n\что то $stripsCountView
 \n\имя $sname \n\фамилия $fname \n\город $city \n\почта $email \n\телефон $phone \n\комментарий $comment \n\Оплата  $paytype  $gogo";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
}
```

}

```
<form method="post" id="orderForm" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" onsubmit="yaCounter22491661.reachGoal('FZakaz'); return true;"> <div class="sendform_title" style="font-weight: 700;">Стоимость, руб:</div>
<div class="sendform_data"><span id="costView"><i>Выберите текстуру</i></span></div> <div style="clear: both;"></div> <div style="height: 20px;"></div>
<div class="sendform_title">Выбранная текстура:</div> <div class="sendform_data"><div id="textureView" style="height: 21px; margin-bottom: 3px; padding: 3px 0px;">-</div></div> <div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: <a href="#" class="texture-js-increase" id="textureLink_2" onclick="SetLayer('2', '/pesok.png', '890', 'Песок', '125'); return false;"><div><div><img src="aqw_files/pesok-mini.png" alt="" align="left"></div></div><span style="position: relative; top: -8px;">Песок</span></a></td><td style="width: 120px;" valign="middle">
/********************************************************/
немного похимичил, теперь на почту приходит id текстуры, а не название, почему на сайте выводится название а на почту только id?

Comment: Что-то не увидел в "коде формы" ни одного элемента с данными. Что отправить-то пытаемся?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, сюда нужен код формы. Тут нигде нет отправки Post'ом, только приём

Comment: Я имею ввиду: сюда - на наше обозрение

Comment: я его впихнул в первый комментарий - ни как не получалось его в сам вопрос вставить -

Comment: <form method="post" id="orderForm" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" onsubmit="yaCounter22491661.reachGoal('FZakaz'); return true;">
<div class="sendform_title" style="font-weight: 700;">Стоимость, руб:</div>

<div class="sendform_data"><span id="costView"><i>Выберите текстуру</i></span></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div style="height: 20px;"></div>
 
<div class="sendform_title">Выбранная текстура:</div>
<div class="sendform_data"><div id="textureView" style="height: 21px; margin-bottom: 3px; padding: 3px 0px;">-</div></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>

Comment: <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method = "post">  
Вроде надо так, зачем у вас '=' после '<?'?
Да, может я ошибаюсь, и надо вставить вот так:  
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "post">

Comment: @psix-dev, это [относительно] недавно введенная форма короткой записи <?php echo [content]; ?>, эта часть должна работать.

Answer (score 0):

```
onsubmit="yaCounter22491661.reachGoal('FZakaz');
```

код этой функции в студию

Comment: это просто яндекс метрика